# Check if all item in Recyclerview have the esame value

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a list of task using recyclerview. Before user can proceed or submit report, all the task in the list must have been done. my question is, how can i check if all the items in recyclerview have the same value (taskStatus) ?

Comment: thats what `hashcode()` and `equals()` are for ..

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it is to add in your adapter a method "boolean areTasksDone(){...}" where you check the validity of your list items. Before submit you can use that method to know if everything is completed.